# Using MS Flow with SharePoint and Teams to notify when changes are made to an Excel file?

Tags: excel, microsoft-teams

I [read](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams/Notification-of-file-upload-in-channel/m-p/125134) that the Teams `Files` uses SharePoint as it's backend.

There's an Excel file in Teams that we want people to be able to edit and then send an email and display in Teams Channel Chat when it has been edited.

Is it possible to do this?  I also read that one needs to use MS Flow to do this; but how does this work without sending an email every time someone clicks the save button?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a flow that runs on item change in the SP library, and then have it email the Team email address.  As you stated though, every time a change is made it will send an email.

Comment: Well what if it generates a new file from a template every time?